# Log rotation creating more files than mentioned with rotate attribute

Tags: linux, logrotate

```
#cat /etc/logrotate.d/pcsd  
/var/log/pcsd/*.log {  
    rotate 5  
    weekly  
    missingok  
    notifempty  
    compress  
    delaycompress  
    copytruncate  
    create 0600 root root  
}
```

Ideally there should be max 5 pcsd.log files. However I am seeing huge number of backedup files(more than 100 log files).

```
-rw-------.  1 root root 230M Apr  9 00:01 pcsd.log-20230409-2023040900.backup  
-rw-------.  1 root root  15M Apr 16 00:01 pcsd.log-20230409.gz-2023041600.backup  
-rw-------.  1 root root  16M Apr 16 00:01 pcsd.log-20230416.gz  
-rw-------.  1 root root 247M Apr 16 00:01 pcsd.log-20230416-2023041600.backup  
-rw-------.  1 root root  17M Apr 23 00:01 pcsd.log-20230423.gz  
-rw-------.  1 root root  16M Apr 23 00:01 pcsd.log-20230416.gz-2023042300.backup  
-rw-------.  1 root root 254M Apr 23 00:01 pcsd.log-20230423-2023042300.backup  
-rw-------.  1 root root  17M Apr 30 00:01 pcsd.log-20230423.gz-2023043000.backup  
-rw-------.  1 root root  17M Apr 30 00:01 pcsd.log-20230430.gz  
-rw-------.  1 root root 252M Apr 30 00:01 pcsd.log-20230430-2023043000.backup  
-rw-------.  1 root root  17M May  7 00:01 pcsd.log-20230430.gz-2023050700.backup  
-rw-------.  1 root root  17M May  7 00:01 pcsd.log-20230507.gz  
-rw-------.  1 root root 252M May  7 00:01 pcsd.log-20230507-2023050700.backup  
-rw-------.  1 root root  17M May 14 00:01 pcsd.log-20230507.gz-2023051400.backup  
-rw-------.  1 root root 251M May 14 00:01 pcsd.log-20230514-2023051400.backup  
-rw-------.  1 root root 251M May 14 00:01 pcsd.log-20230514
```

/etc/logrotate.conf also has below configurations. looking at the extension of the backed up files, I think below dateext getting applied. seems this configuration is a default one. How can I restrict the max number of pcsd log files to 5?

```
weekly
rotate 4
create
dateext
include /etc/logrotate.d
```

Comment: Are there any files with a name ending in `.log` in that folder at all?

Comment: I see below files without .backup extension
`-rw-------. 1 root root  16M Apr 16 00:01 pcsd.log-20230416.gz
-rw-------. 1 root root  17M May  7 00:01 pcsd.log-20230507.gz
-rw-------. 1 root root  17M Apr 30 00:01 pcsd.log-20230430.gz
-rw-------. 1 root root  17M Apr 23 00:01 pcsd.log-20230423.gz
-rw-------. 1 root root 165M May 18 14:29 pcsd.log
-rw-------. 1 root root 251M May 14 00:01 pcsd.log-20230514`

Comment: Would be good if you add those to your question. (TBH I have no clue, but would think that the backup files are not made by logrotate). Are there any postrotate scripts that could cause them?